# PyMongo: How to use the projection operators - $slice - in find() in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How should I do to use the python api to perform this query:

`db.collection.find( { field: value }, { array: {$slice: count } } );`

When I use the projection operators, I can not use the include specifications at the same time. How can I do simply to access the specific filed without any other fields which might have a large amounts of data.

Comment: Try this `db.collection.find( { "field": value }, { "field": 1, "array": {"$slice": count } } )`

Answer (score 2):

Same as any other query. The parameters are Python dictionaries, and the keys are always strings.

```
db.collection.find( { "field": value }, { "array": {"$slice": count } } );
```

Comment: I want to use both the projection operators and include specifications to make sure that the only one field can be returned, because the other fields might have a large data. Is there a simple query can handle it?

Comment: By the way, the solution brought by you does work to solve the 'slice', but I can not  vote because of the reputation. So thanks.